# Как правильней организовать ajax запрос с подгрузкой данных?

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

На страницу необходимо посредством ajax выводить данные (HTML). Данные формируются в цикле в файле PHP. Вот что делаю.

**Javascript**

```
$(".nameClass").load( // Скрипт начинает работу сразу после загрузки страницы
"dannie.php", {
    param: "znach"
},

function () {});
```

**PHP**

```
$param = $_POST['param'];
require_once 'connect.php';  // Соединяюсь с БД

$zap = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY '.$param);

while ($mass = mysql_fetch_array($zap)){

    echo "<br/> ";
    echo "<div>".$mass['name']."</div>";

}
```

Ошибки никакие не выдает ни js, ни php. Если выводить без ajax, всё прекрасно работает. А необходимо именно через ajax.

Comment: Естественно библиотека jQuery подключена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
$(".nameClass").load("dannie.php", { 'znach': 'value' } );
```

Comment: лучше так: $(".nameClass").load("dannie.php", {znach: 'value' } );

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: ajax должен дергать dannie.php, не знаю почему у вас он не рисует DIV

Попробуйте еще раз пошерудить Firebag`ом

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но всё оказалось гораздо проще. Моя не внимательность. Элементарно указал не то имя класса для diva куда должно подгружаться содержимое.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nameClass").load(  // Скрипт начинает работу сразу после загрузки страницы
      "dannie.php",
      {
        param: "znach"
      },
      function(){}
    );
});
```

Comment: Улыбнуло )
Да, так и сделано. Но явно причина не в этом, так как остальной скрипт работает.

Comment: Больше кода предоставьте, скорее всего не здесь ошибку искать надо